# Prohibit drag&drop from my application into my application

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I just implemented drag&drop in my application. It goes two ways:

1. From my app to Windows Explorer: exports files
2. From Windows Explorer to my app: imports files

One side effect is that I can also drag files from my application to my application (the same window), which **is not intended.**

Is there a elegant way to make sure, that a drag&drop operation I started won't be accepted by my application? E.g. check if the source of the drop operation != my application?

Comment: how are you doing the drag and drop?

Comment: There is only one way I know of: 'DoDragDrop(myData, DragDropEffects.Copy);'

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the fact that you initiated a drag from inside your application with some sort of facility or service. If you receive a drop on your application, ask the facility/service if the drag was initiated within your application. If so, discard. Reset the facility/service afterwards (in any case).

Comment: The problem is that in both directions I need to drag 'DataFormats.FileDrop' (file names)...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a way to do this.
Now I set two types of data on my drag&drop data object:

1. The file names I want to export
2. A Unicode-Text object containing the name of my application

In my Drop-handler I check if a Unicode-Text object is present and if it contains my application's name. If so, I abort the drop operation.